# How to cancel time conversion in librecalc?

Tags: libreoffice

Whenever I add an "hour" entry on a *LibreOffice Calc* field, it converts into a full hour format after I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

e.g. I get the following conversion:

`17:00` => `05:00:00PM`

[image: screenshoot]

Any idea how to disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select a different time format to format the time value:

1. select the cells to format
2. right-click on them
3. select "`Format Cells...`"
4. From the leftmost listbox ("`Category`"), select "`Time`"
5. From the listbox in the middle ("`Format`"), select the appropriate entry.

[image]